# How to show all x-tick labels with seaborn.objects

Tags: python, seaborn, xticks, seaborn-0.12.x

How do I make it so that it shows all x ticks from 0 to 9?

```
 bin      diff
1       4 -0.032748
3       9  0.106409
13      7  0.057214
17      3  0.157840
19      0 -0.086567
...   ...       ...
1941    0  0.014386
1945    4  0.049601
1947    9  0.059406
1957    1  0.045282
1959    6 -0.033853
```

```
    (
    so.Plot(x='bin', y='diff', data=diff_df) 
    .theme({**axes_style("whitegrid"), "grid.linestyle": ":"})
    .add(so.Dots())
    .add(so.Range(color='orange'), so.Est())
    .add(so.Dot(color='orange'), so.Agg())
    .add(so.Line(color='orange'), so.Agg())
    .label(
        x="Image Similarity Bin", y="Difference",
        color=str.capitalize,
    )
  )
```

I tried to set `xticks` in .label, but it doesn't do anything.

[image: Now it only shows 0, 2, 4...]

Comment: If you liked the jitter that was shown in my deleted solution, you can change `.add(so.Dots())` to `.add(so.Dot(fill=None), so.Dodge(), so.Jitter(.3))` as per [`seaborn.objects.Dot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Dot.html) and [Resolving overplotting](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#resolving-overplotting), which results in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdSwD.png) in conjunction with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- As per [Parameterizing scales](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#parameterizing-scales) and [Customizing legends and ticks](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#customizing-legends-and-ticks), use [`seaborn.objects.Continuous.tick`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Continuous.html#seaborn.objects.Continuous.tick) inside [`seaborn.objects.Plot.scale`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.scale.html)

  - `.scale(x=so.Continuous().tick(every=1))`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn.objects as so

# sample data
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 1100
data = {'diff': np.random.random(size=rows), 'bin': np.random.choice(range(10), size=rows)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
(so.Plot(x='bin', y='diff', data=df)
 .add(so.Dots())
 .add(so.Range(color='orange'), so.Est())
 .add(so.Dot(color='orange'), so.Agg())
 .add(so.Line(color='orange'), so.Agg())
 .label(x="Image Similarity Bin", y="Difference", color=str.capitalize)
 .scale(x=so.Continuous().tick(every=1)))  # adjust the ticks here
```

[image]